# sqlncli10 Native SQL Provider?

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I have a classic ASP page that connects to a SQL Server 2008 database. The connection by this page uses the latest Native SQL Client Provider called 'sqlncli10'.

My question is: Does the Native SQL Provider need to be installed on the web server side or on the database server side? The web server and database server have their own dedicated boxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the connection on the page uses SQLNCLI10, it needs to be installed on the web server side. Remember that the provider is used by the **client** side, not the server side, and in this case your web page as it's being created on the server is the client.